# How can I use a custom generic interface implementation with private types?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

Let's say I want to specify which implementation of a generic interface to use in my class. This is simple (if a little ugly) if the class is using it to store another public type:

```
class Foo<T> where T : IList<Bar>, new()
{
    private T _list = new T();
}
class Bar{}
```

We can then make a new instance of foo as such: `new Foo<List<Bar>>()`

But what happens `Bar` is a private class within `Foo`:

```
class Foo<T> where T : IList<Bar>, new()
{
    private T _list = new T();
    class Bar{}
}
```

Obviously this fails because `Foo` can't expose `Bar` in its type constraints, and there's no way to instantiate a  `new Foo<List<Bar>>()`

I could stick with exposing `object`:

```
class Foo<T> where T : IList<object>, new()
{
    private T _list = new T();
    class Bar{}
}
```

But then I'm casting from `object` to `Bar` every time I use the interface.

What is my best option here?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of private is enable access only by the code in the same class. Simply what you are try to do is not correct. better change that private to other access modifier according to your requirement.

Comment: I'm not trying to expose `Bar`. I would prefer not to. I simply need to use it internally, with a passed-in generic type.

Answer (score 0):

What about exposing a second type parameter in the Foo class exposing the instance type of the collection, something like:

```
class Foo<TList, TItem> where TList : IList<TItem>, new()
{
    private IList<TItem> _list = new TList();

    public Foo()
    {
    }


    public void Add(TItem item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And then make a concrete class for holding bar like

```
class BarFoo : Foo<List<BarFoo.Bar>, BarFoo.Bar>
{
    class Bar { }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about not posting my full answer at once, something went wrong with copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best option is:

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> _list = List<Bar>();
    class Bar{}
}
```

The only reason I can fathom to make Foo a generic class to wrap a list of some private, nested class would be if you had a private nested class hierarchy with Bar inheritors.  And, if that were the case, you could just expose some kind of factory method that took a parameter necessary to tell Foo which sub class clients wanted.  If you're keeping the type of the list and the list both private, making the class's public API generic makes no sense, IMO.  You're demanding that clients supply a type they have no access to or control over.